# How to handle multiple images with scrollview in android Jelly Bean

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-4.2-jelly-bean

i thought best way to handle a lot of images in scrollview is using recyclerview, my app that used recyclerview works on android Marshmellow, but it doesn't work in android jelly bean, and i just knowing that cardview and recyclerview is introduced in android Lolipop, so how to handle a lot of images in scrollview without recyclerview.

Comment: Card view and Recycle view also work for android Jelly Bean. what issue you are facing in android Jelly Bean ?

Comment: my app freezing for a while then force closed

Comment: What error you are getting in log ?